# Python exception finally didnt work

Tags: python

I was learning python exceptions and I have tried something like this

```
try:
 fh = open("testfile", "r")
fh.write("This is my test file for exception handling!!")

except IOError:
print "Error: can\'t find file or read data"
else:

   print "Written content in the file successfully"

finally:
print "our exceptions are false"
```

When I executed the code without the `finally` section I got can't find or read data as output and when I executed the code with `finally` I get an Indentation error. I don't know why this happened.

Comment: You are getting an indentation error because your code is not properly indented.

Comment: Your post is having serious indentation errors here too; we cannot make heads nor tails of what error you actually saw. Please post your *exact* code then select the code block and use the `{}` button on the toolbar to format it. Please also give us the exact exception you get.

Comment: I have only this code which i have posted here .am just a beginner in python ..Can you please tell me how to use finally here ?..

Comment: read this then: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Indentation

Comment: just indent your code & there won't be any errors left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the main problem with your code is the indentation. Here's a possible solution for it.

Python requires an indentation after some statements, some of them are conditionals, loops, exception handling,  functions and classes, that way code is more legible and easy to understand.

for example, here is a function. Just seeing the code you can see what happens, occurs 'within the function'

```
def f(arg=i):
    print arg
```

and is similar to what happen when you're working with a conditional,  loop, the different in indentation states what happens 'within' the loop.

```
a = ['Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb']
for i in range(len(a)):
     print i, a[i]
```

Exceptions have blocks of codes because they represents different test cases. as show below.

```
try:
         x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
         print x
         break
     except ValueError:
         print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
```

The level of indentation of the code is called code nesting, you can have multiple levels of indentation when working with multiple of this categories (loops, exceptions handling, functions and classes). The code below has two levels of indentation.

```
def fib(n):                   1
    print 'n =', n            2
    if n > 1:                 3
        return n * fib(n - 1)
    else:                     4
        print 'end of the line'
        return 1
```

A solution that can work is this.

```
try:
    fh = open("testfile", "r")
    fh.write("This is my test file for exception handling!!")

except IOError:
    print "Error: can\'t find file or read data"
else:
    #I think this should be done here
    fh.close()
    print "Written content in the file successfully"
finally:
    print "our exceptions are false"
```

Comment: Gave OP the answer and OP learned nothing.   |=^/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the finally that is the issue but your [indentation](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html).

For example, this:

```
try:
 fh = open("testfile", "r")
fh.write("This is my test file for exception handling!!")
```

It's not going to work because Python requires you to indent your code.  You want it to look as so:

```
try:
    #every new block is evenly indented
    fh = open("testfile", "r")
    fh.write("This is my test file for exception handling!!")
```

This is now properly indented for Python (and is even easier to read).  You need to fix this in all your code similar to the following format:

```
#creating new block (try block)
try:
    #code
    #indented
    #here
#creating new block (except block)
except IOError:
    #handle
    #error
#rest of your code
```